# Installing a 3-prong dryer in an old house

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to install a dryer I got for free into this old house, and I'm not sure I have the correct wiring to do it. I've replaced one of those standard 3-prong outlets before, because it wouldn't hold any plugs in, but this has me confused.

I went to The Home Depot and showed an assistant a picture of the dryer plug, he immediately grabbed me one of these, said it'd be easy and I could just follow videos on YouTube:

[image: dryer 3 prong outlet]

Back:

[image: back of dryer 3 prong]

Thinking everything would be easy, I dove in and (after flipping off the house breaker) disconnected the target wall plug:

[image: regular 3 prong outlet]

However, I'm unsure of how to proceed, and the information online seems to have differing opinions. Some say I need to get a 4 prong outlet and re-wire the dryer to make it 4 prong, some say that it can't be done with this outlet, and I'm at a loss for what to do. These are the wires sticking out of the wall:

[image: wall wires]

There's another bare box nearby that only appears to have 2 wires sticking out of it, I'm not sure if it's of any help:

[image: other outlet]

I'm not sure what to do -- do I have the right plugs to be able to pull this upgrade off?

Comment: Most electric dryers use 240 VAC.  The outlet you are trying to replace is a regular household 120 VAC outlet.  You will probably need an electrician to run a 240 VAC line from your distribution box to your dryer.

Comment: Did the house have an electric dryer beforehand, or a gas dryer?

Comment: This is dead proof that one should know what they are doing BEFORE removing devices and wiring. What you propose CANNOT be done without running a new circuit, which could have been explained if you had just investigated a bit before starting.

Comment: I have upvoted your question, because it is a good question. The answers are also good. I do not understand downvoting questions that are complete, clear and reflect a desire to learn.  In addition, you received bad information from Home Depot - they didn't ask about the outlet you are replacing, so your question is doubly important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dryer requires a 120/240 volt 30 ampere circuit.  The receptacle you removed is on a 120 volt 15 or 20 ampere circuit.  The wiring and overcurrent protection for that circuit are not large enough to supply a dryer.

If you don't have an existing 120/240 volt 30 ampere circuit, you'll have to install one.  Installing a **new** dryer circuit requires.

- Installing a 30 ampere double pole breaker in the panel.
- Pulling four 10 AWG copper conductors (or 10/3 with ground cable), between the panel and a box near the location where the dryer will be installed.
- Install a NEMA 14-30R receptacle in a box where the dryer will be installed..
- Follow the manufacturer's installation instructions to install a 4-prong cord on the dryer.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't -- the NEMA 10 you have is a 120/240V outlet -- the junction box you pulled the outlet from, however, only has a single 120V branch circuit in it.  (The empty box is likely the same way, too, although one would need to measure the voltage from hot to neutral to be sure.)